# Authorizing service account to access Picasa private data

Tags: java, google-api, picasa

I try using the OAuth2 authentication with the PicasaService in a Java application.

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
 <artifactId>core</artifactId>
 <version>${version.gdata}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
 <version>${version.google-api-services-oauth2}</version>
</dependency>
```

Versions:

```
<version.gdata>1.47.1</version.gdata>
<version.google-api-services-oauth2>v2-rev93-1.20.0</version.google-api-services-oauth2>
```

I logged in with the album owner account to the Developers Console and created a service account and downloaded the p12 key file.

I'm trying to authenticate with the service account:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("privatekey.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://picasaweb.google.com/data"))
            .build();

credential.refreshToken();
```

It's working fine, the authentication is OK and an access token is retrieved.

I can check the retrieved token with https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=TOKEN

```
{
issued_to: "XXX",
audience: "XXX",
scope: "https://picasaweb.google.com/data",
expires_in: 3542,
access_type: "offline"
}
```

The PicasaService is using the authenticated GoogleCredentials:

```
PicasaService picasaService = new PicasaService("appname-from-developers-console");
picasaService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

The service API calls returning with no error but the returned data contains only publicly available data, so it's like an unauthorized access.

If I add the **setServiceAccountUser()** call to the GoogleCredential builder where the parameter value is the Picasa account's login name then **refreshToken()** throws a **TokenResponseException** that says the call is unauthorized (401) so it's like the service account has no access to this Picasa account however the Picasa account created the service account.

On the developer console where I can select what APIs I'd like to use there is no Picasa/Photo whatever that has anything to do with the uploaded photos except the Google Picker API that says: "Google Picker API enables users to select photos, videos, maps and documents stored in Google servers." but it did not help.

My question is how can I authorize the service account to have access to the private data or where is my code went wrong?

Comment: Hi, it's been a long while, Have you solved this?